# Is it possible to create a device specific .plist file -iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, plist, data-sharing

I am storing some data in a plist file.. and I have realised that it can be shared. Is there a way where I can make .plist files device specific? Maybe UDID or something? Any ideas will be much appreciated..

Comment: Are you creating the plist file at runtime ?

Comment: Yes I am.. after the 1st product is purchased.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want others to see the contents of your .plist files, you could encrypt them with iOS provided [encryption algorithms](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172-CH9-SW14).
Other simple way would be storing your sensitive data in the keychain, or `NSUserDefaults` without writing to file, which would be very device specific. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I am storing information of purchased  products. Even if I encrypt it, it wouldn't make much of a difference since the decryption algorithm will be the same within my app. Someone can buy something and share the plist file easily.. I am not really sure if keychain will suit for that purpose but I will certainly check that out..

Comment: Yeah, then in your case, `NSUserDefaults` or keychain is the way to go.

Comment: And, for each device you could use different keys for encrypting, like `UDID`, which is deprecated, or unique strings, UUID for example.

Answer (score 0):

UDID is banned from 1st May 2013.

From iOS 6 onwards there is one additional method called `identifierForVendor`. You can use this method for creating a unique Identifier for your App in each iOS device.

You can get it like:

```
NSString *idForApp = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
```

Save your `plist` using the `idForApp`. It'll be unique.

> **identifierForVendor**
>
> An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a device to the app’s
>   vendor. (read-only)
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSUUID *identifierForVendor;
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the
>   same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned
>   for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for
>   apps on different devices regardless of vendor.
>
> The value of this property may be nil if the app is running in the
>   background, before the user has unlocked the device the first time
>   after the device has been restarted. If the value is nil, wait and get
>   the value again later.
>
> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another
>   app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value
>   changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the
>   device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. Therefore, if
>   your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should
>   gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.
>
> **Availability**
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 6.0 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In UIDevice.h

Reference :

- [UIDevice Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html)
- [UDID Replacement](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/09/udid-apis-in-ios-6/)

---

Also you can use the `UUID` class method of `NSUUID` class for creating an unique id.

[NSUUID - UUID](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUUID_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSUUID/UUID)

Comment: Thanks.. identifierForVendor and uniqueIdentifier seem like returning different results. If someone buys something on iOS 5 and later he upgrades OS to 6+ then this wouldn't work. Am I right?

Comment: @user968173 Yes. In iOS 6 the uniqueIdentifier Won't work. So for iOS 5 use uniqueIdentifier and store the value in NSUserDefaults. Or simply use NSUUID class for creating unique Identifier and save it in database.