# Identifying devices uniquely

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using UUID for blocking users from using my application, when they violates rules of  application. But UUID is deprecated in iphone so now i am creating a custom uuid and saving it in keychain.

Now i want to know when keychain values are reset? Are values in keychain goes away when user update iOS or reset iphone.

Comment: This not your answer in any way but have a look at : http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/

Comment: Do not track users by any device-specific ID. People sell their devices, or return them to apple to be refurbished or give them to their family members or whatever. You can't identify users by the device and you just cause problems to future owners.

Comment: i think i can use Identifier for Vendor (IDFV). For detail check above link

Comment: yes, you are right, Mike Weller. I am not adding a new feature in the but i had to update existing code to work with deprecated UUID feature. :)

Comment: @Developer: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411698/is-it-possible-to-create-a-device-specific-plist-file-ios/16412775#16412775 Device specific Id

Answer (score 1):

The keychain is cleared if the user resets their phone.

Comment: any other way to identify users device. Will mac address will work?

Answer (score 1):

you can use mac address. It's not deprecated yet :)

Answer (score 0):

No the values that are stored in the key chain does't go away until you clear it but if you reset the phone it ll go away.